# Should I always keep my professor in cc

Tags: phd, postdocs

I have recently joined as a research staff (after finishing my PhD) under a professor, and my primary duty is to interact and provide day-to-day support (mostly academically) to all of his PhD students. Should I always keep my professor in cc when interacting with the students via Email?

Comment: Ask your professor what they prefer? (though in general I would assume "no")

Comment: @xLeitix, that seems to be the only reasonable answer. Why not make it so? Only the professor has an answer for this.

Comment: Related from a more general workplace perspective: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/14510/63134

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to ask your professor. Some of them always want to be kept in the loop while others prefer a cleaner email inbox. There is no way around asking him directly (which shouldn't be a problem anyway?).

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the professor, some of them like to be in every correspondence, while others like to have a general overview of how the student are.

In general, as suggested by other users, I would suggest that you talk to the professor, since he is the one who offered you the "research staff" position in the first place and see his preference. And maybe explore the difference avenues with him, maybe

1. Daily update
2. Weekly summary

Or you could keep CCing him on Email tell he starts to complain about it (though I would not recommend this)